# OpenSSL: can output size of EVP_DigestFinal_ex be greater than the digest size?

Tags: hash, openssl, sha, digest, message-digest

[OpenSSL EVP_DigestFinal_ex](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/EVP_DigestInit.html) has the following documentation:

"EVP_DigestFinal_ex() retrieves the digest value from ctx and places it in md. If the s parameter is not NULL then the number of bytes of data written (i.e. the length of the digest) will be written to the integer at s, at most EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE bytes will be written."

**Signature:**

```
int EVP_DigestFinal_ex(EVP_MD_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *md, unsigned int *s);
```

Are there any cases where the digest length will be greater than the output size of the digest yet smaller than EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE. i.e. for SHA-1 digest, I get an output which is greater than 20bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relevant source code from OpenSSL [crypto/evp/digest.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/evp/digest.c#L247):

```
    OPENSSL_assert(ctx->digest->md_size <= EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE);
    ret = ctx->digest->final(ctx, md);
    if (size != NULL)
       *size = ctx->digest->md_size;
```

where *size* is your desired output digest size, and *digest* is a **const** structure which in case of SHA1 is being defined in [crypto/evp/m_sha1.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/evp/m_sha1.c#L84):

```
static const EVP_MD sha1_md = {
     NID_sha1,
     NID_sha1WithRSAEncryption,
     SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH
```

md_size is the third member of this structure, so it always will be  *SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH* which is [equal to](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/include/openssl/sha.h#L81) **20**